# Combine 2 columns into 1; removing NAs; Incorrect number of Dimensions in R

Tags: r

I have a 8 column data frame. I want to combine 2 columns of a data frame into one (column 6 and 8.) Both of these columns contain the same data. I basically want to remove the "NAs" such that there are 3 rows of "South West" and last row of "South East"

> 6th column      8th Column 
>   NA     -----------         South West 
>   NA  -----------            South West 
>   NA   -----------           South West 
>   South East    --   NA

I subset the data frame to only pull columns 6 and 8 (the columns that I would like to combine.)
`region_merge = df[,c(6,8)]`

I created my own function as below:

`comb_region <- function(df){
  if (df[,6]=="NA")
    df[,6] = df[,8]
  else
    df[,6] = df[,6]
}`

I then used the apply function to repeat the function across all my rows:

```
apply(X = region_merge, MARGIN = 1, FUN = comb_region)
```

However, I get the error: `Error in df[, 6] : incorrect number of dimensions`

I'm new to R. Could someone help me understand why I am getting this error?

Alternatively - Do you guys know an **alternative solution** to merge 2 columns in 1, by removing the "NAs"?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: One possible mistake in the code is that, once you pick columns 6 and 8, your function should not refer to columns 6 and 8, but rather 1 and 2. That, however, would likely give you a different error message.

Comment: you probably want something like `region <- ifelse(is.na(df[[6]]), df[[8]], df[[6]])` instead of using `apply`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
comb_region <- function(df)
 {
 df[,6]=ifelse(is.na(df[,6]), df[,8], df[,6]);
 df[,8]=ifelse(is.na(df[,8]), df[,6], df[,8]);
 return(df)
 }
filled_df=comb_region(df_with_nas)
```

Direct comparisons to NA typically do not work: use is.na instead.

And notice that the region_merge data.frame you are passing to comb_region only has two columns.